# How will HAP over cloud will work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, homekit

Apple have added new features in Homekit framework in iOS 9.
I have seen [What's New in HomeKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=210). 
In that they have added support of Homekit Accessory Protocol (HAP) over cloud. 
 But they didn't tell how it will work, what developers need to do to support accessories to accessible from apple's cloud services.

I have reviewed their HAP for IP Accessories R3 document, but that document also didn't have any information on this.
What I am looking for is, there should be something at Accessory (Light, Thermostate or bridge) which is added to home in Homekit enabled application and which is accessible for user logged in with icloud account.
Now, to support HAP over cloud at accessory side developer needs to do something so that it can identify for user for which its configured.

So what are the changes require at bridge(gateway or hub) or accessory to implement HAP protocol over cloud?

Comment: Its not open ended. I have given information about ios version, framework i.e Homekit, described the feature as well as my question. And also given link of wwdc 2015 video.  It requires knowledge about apple Homekit to answer this question.

Comment: hello samir did you get any information about it? Even me also looking for implementing proximity ? This is working on basis of iCloud ... Thanks Srinu

Comment: No, I didn't get the answer. Apple's document for iOS 9 for Homekit didn't have much detail. However I found that accessories required to add certificate in it. That can be found at MFi portal of apple. I don't if its true or not.

Comment: Thank you Samir what I read from the apple documents is Eventhough you are away from home using iCloud account we can control using the Same iCloud account on device and apple TV but didn't find any functionality related information https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204893 .

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on HAP Over iCloud concept since last 2 to 3  hours. The beauty in this concept is according to the documentation we should need the following things.

1. Apple tv 3rd generation
2. Have to use same iCloud account in both apple tv and iOS device.
3. This is most important that Apple tv and Accessory should be on same network.

Eventhough you are on different network it is able to pass the switch on/off,brightness increase/decrease ... actions. For this you can use siri commands or programmatically call the accessory write value functionality

Note : As I know I think when you are passing the commands to the Accessory it checks for the iCloud account in the apple tv and from there it is passing the commands to the Accessory. The apple tv and the accessory both are in same network so apple tv will reach that accessory. Thus apple tv acts as a mediator between the iOS device and Accessory

Comment: small drawback is it is taking little bit of extra time for performing action. It is working fine at my end. Please let me know if there are any issues